# Microsoft.Build Project class fails to load f# project file

Tags: .net, f#, msbuild

I have this simple c# program (to demonstrate the issue):

```
Project p = new Project("MyProject.fsproj");
Console.WriteLine("Project loaded {0}", p.FullPath);
```

On my primary computer this works perfectly. However, when attempting to open the same .fsproj file on another machine it fails with:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The value ""
>   of the "Project" attribute in element  is invalid. Parameter
>   "path" cannot have zero length.  C:\temp\MyProject.fsproj.

Both machines have:

- VS2013 premium Update 4
- MSBuild version 12.0.31101.0
- .Net 4.5.2
- Microsoft Visual F# 3.1.2

I assume the exception is referring to this part of the project file and perhaps $(FSharpTargetsPath) isn't being filled in?

```
<Choose>
<When Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '11.0'">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\..\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets')">
    <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\..\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</When>
<Otherwise>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\FSharp\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets')">
    <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\FSharp\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Otherwise>
</Choose>
<Import Project="$(FSharpTargetsPath)" />
```

Comment: F# targets are probably missing from `Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/F#/3.1/Framework/v4.0`, file `Microsoft.FSharp.targets` and/or `Microsoft.Portable.FSharp.targets`, which should not happen if you have F# SDK installed - I remember having similar (or even exactly the same) error on TeamCity server when I forgot to install F#.

Comment: Thank you Patryk. Those files exist. They also exist at C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\FSharp\ - and when I modify the Import in the project file to refer to that path it works. I guess this is a problem with what MSBuildExtensionsPath32 is resolving as?

Comment: What's your `$(VisualStudioVersion)` in both cases?

Comment: It's 12.0 in both cases

Comment: open a bug at https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/